# listview:Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have the following issue in listview in android:

In my application I have 2 databases, I have to show this 2 databases in a single listview with a separator between them.  Before I tried by using 2 listview that works fine, but now I want it all in a single listview.  Please provide some design for this.

Comment: can simply create a custom adapter... and while join the array list pass any string identifier which will help you to set the position of separator in list

Answer (score 1):

Try CommonWare's [MergeAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge).

From the docs for it:

> MergeAdapter accepts a mix of Adapters and Views and presents them as
>   one contiguous whole to whatever ListView it is poured into. This is
>   good for cases where you have multiple data sources, or if you have a
>   handful of ordinary Views to mix in with lists of data, or the like.

So you can create a seperate adapter for each DB, a View to seperate them, pour them into the MergeAdapter and use that to populate a single list.

Pseudo-code example:

```
myMergeAdapter = new MergeAdapter(); 
myMergeAdapter.addAdapter(listAdapter1); 
myMergeAdapter.addView(SeperatorView); 
myMergeAdapter.addAdapter(listAdapter2);
```